# efficient diff between large file and other small files

Tags: file-io, random, diff

I wish to get some expert advice on this problem.

I have two text files, one very large ( ~ GB ) and other small ( ~ MB). These files essentially have information per line. I can say that bigger file has a subset of information about the smaller file. Each line in files is organized as tuples sperated by spaces and diff is found by looking at one or more of columns in those two files. Both of these files are sorted based on one of such column (document id).

I implemented it by keeping index on document id and line number and doing a random access to that line in larger file to start the diff. But this method is slow. I want to know any good mechanism for this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want to check if two lines with same document id in two files are different on other columns?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are known to be sorted in the same order by the same key, and the lines that share a common key are expected to match exactly, then `comm` is probably what you want - it has flags to allow you to show only the lines that are common between two files, or the lines that are in one file but not the other.